# Calling R from S-Plus?

Tags: r, s-plus, s

Does anyone have any suggestions for a good way to call R from S-Plus?  Ideally I would like to just pass code to R and get data back without having to write anything too elaborate to integrate them.

I should add that I'm familiar with the [RinS](http://www.omegahat.org/RinS/) package on Omegahat, but I haven't used it.  I was under the impression that Insightful had made an effort to integrate the environments before Tibco took over.

*Edit:* It turns out that RinS doesn't work on Windows.  I found that the easiest solution was to just use Rscript.  I can call this from S-Plus with the `system()` command.  For example, here's a simple script:

```
#! Rscript --vanilla --default-packages=utils
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(args)
print(1:100)
Sys.sleep(2)
res <- "hello world"
class(res) <- "try-error"
if(inherits(res, "try-error")) q(status=1) else q()
```

And calling it from S-Plus:

```
system("rscript c://test.rscript 'some text'")
```

Then I just store the results into a text file and import it into S-Plus after the script is run.

Comment: What's S-Plus?  Sorry, couldn't resist ...

Comment: Ouch...  :)  It's R for dummies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RSPlus** is the only option i'm aware of. I used it almost daily for about a year, but haven't used it since R 2.7.  From your Q, it seems like you just want to run R inside SPlus, which RSPlus can certainly do (R is a separate interpreter accessible via an interface comprised of a few SPlus functions, the most-often used is '.R()', e.g., .R("fivenum", 1:10).

I think we are talking about the same thing though, because 'RinS' is one of two modules (SpinR being the other) that together comprise RSPlus (i.e., there's only a single interface, regardless of the direction you want to go--R to SPlus, or SPllus to R). Although it wasn't obvious to me at the time, i had to install both modules to get RinS to work.